# Multiple Vertex Buffers per Mesh

Tags: c++, opengl, vbo, opengl-3, buffer

I've run into the situation where the size of my mesh with all its vertices and indices, is larger than the (optimal) vertex buffer object upper limit (~8MB). I was wondering if I can sub-divide the mesh across multiple vertex buffers, and somehow retain validity of the indices. Ie a triangle with a indice at the first vertex, and an indice at the last (ie in seperate VBOs).

All the while maintaining this within Vertex Array Objects.
My thoughts are, save myself the hassle, and for meshes (messes :P) such as this, just use the necessary size (> 8MB); which is what I do at the moment.
But ideally my buffer manager (wip) at the moment is using optimal sizes; I may just have to make a special case then.

Any ideas?

Note: I have also cross-posted this on the [gamedev stack](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/8855/multiple-vertex-buffers-per-mesh), as I was not sure as to which it would be more suitable (its partly a design question).

Comment: Cross-posted: http://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/8855/multiple-vertex-buffers-per-mesh Probably a good idea to add a link to the other question back here, too.

Comment: Thanks, I did originally, but wasn't sure if I should, so I removed it. I will update them now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

8MB of vertex data is quite a lot for a single model. I'm pretty sure this model could be split into individual meshes. Good places for splitting a mesh are sharp edges, since vertices along these edges have different normal vectors are thus not identical and cannot be shared.

However more important than the VBO size is the size of the render batch passed to glDrawElements (or glDrawArrays).  In my experience the optimal size for render batches are between 100 to 2000 triangles, before cache pressure kicks in. But you should measure that on your system yourself.

Comment: I understand your first point, however what do you mean optimal size for render batches?

Comment: The amount of primitives that a call to glDrawElements (or glDrawArrays, but I advise against the use of that) will draw. In case of glDrawElements(mode, count, type, indices), it's simply the value of count. But it really depends on the OpenGL implementation and the data in question, what the optimal value is. You've to experiment with it.

Comment: In most OpenGL applications each distinct "object" visible has some between 100 to 3000 vertices. Complex models are broken down into parts. E.g. it makes little sense to send a complex character model as whole, since that would require all the skeletal and facial animation shaders to be processed on the whole mesh. At least in the games I contributed we've split characters into each leg, each arm and hands. The head portion is split into neck and back of the head; the whole facial area is a complete own mesh, but does not contain the eyes, jaw and tounge, those are animated separately.

Comment: I think I should further point out that one shouldn't switch shaders between batches, but change the code path a shader follows using uniforms. One might think that using vertex attributes may do it as well, but since the attribute is processed for each vertex the performance penality is very high. A uniform with no indirection used in a conditional branch performs much better.

Answer (score 0):

To my knowledge, you can set just one glVertexPointer. So you could set this pointer to your big data storage but that would be in client's memory and without VBO. If you want ot use VBO there can be only one at time.

But actually you could save all your data as texture and use geometry shader to rebuild model just from indices. Texture limit on my Radeon 3870HD is 8192 per dimension, but you are more likely to run out of memory using more than 1D texture (512 mb memory on my card and full 2D RGB texture is around 805 mb). In geometry shader you can connect your vertieces acording to supported indices and create mesh, but it's quite big workaround and not very practical.

As mentioned it's rather waste of resource to do such precise models. In most 3D designers you have modifier to get much less polygons without affecting visuality, you just choose part that is overdetailed. It's also huge performance hit when you think about that most of time you see arround 50% of model and rest is discarded by tests..

Comment: Your first solution is not appropriate, as I intend to use Open GL3 strict.

Comment: well actually it is openGL, you only use RAM instead of VRAM. But as I said you can set only one atribute pointer for each attribute such as gl_Vertex, thus you can't switch buffers in single call, nor connect them into one. You can only divide your model or lower it's details or make big workaround generally disabling vertex shader in this proces (geometry shader comes after vertex shader and if you build your model here you won't be able to use vertex one)